# IdentityServer4 in IIS being recycled due to app_offline.htm when using discovery endpoint sometimes

Tags: iis, identityserver4, .net-5, asp.net5

My IdentityServer being hosted in IIS seems to be recycled due to app_offline.htm according to the Windows application log. It seems to happen sometimes when the Discovery endpoint is being requested, but I can't deduce any obvious pattern to when it does or doesn't happen.

The event description is:

```
Application 'C:\Users\IP21Admin\Desktop\sts\' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm.
```

The last few log entries in the IdentityServer log are:

```
[2021-01-14 17:01:32 DBG] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery

[2021-01-14 17:01:32 DBG] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint

[2021-01-14 17:01:32 INF] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks

[2021-01-14 17:01:32 DBG] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
Start key discovery request
```

I found a similar problem someone posted as an issue int he ASPNET core repository here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21528

I've tried using process monitor to find where app_offline.htm comes from, but every single entry is w2wp.exe operation 'CreateFile' with result 'NAME NOT FOUND'.
[Process Monitor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIrqx.png)

I've tried manually putting in my own app_offline.htm and the process monitor will give completely different operations, which leads me to suspect that there wasn't actually an app_offline.htm being created previously. Perhaps the Windows Application event is misleading and there's some sort of crash happening?

Anyone have any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Edit:
So having looked into this further, the IdentityServer4 instance in IIS seems to get recycled after successfully issuing an Authorisation Code Token from token endpoint. I hooked up remote debugging and saw that when the app is getting recycled, there is 100% CPU usage by the IIS worker, and the process memory of app stays constant; don't know if that's useful information or not.

The symptom of the problem is that when OidcClient of my client GUI application proceeds to get UserInfo from the UserInfo endpoint after getting the Authorisation Code Token; before UserInfo, its attempt to load the discovery document fails due to "Server has been shutdown".

Perhaps the TokenEndpoint causes the middleware to get stuck or something causing a recycle? I assume the server can't respond to the DiscoveryEndpoint request because something in(or after) the TokenEndpoint request caused the server app to get recycled before it could respond to the DiscoveryEndpoint request.

With today's attempts, the log now ends at:

```
[2021-01-15 13:01:23 DBG] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint
Token request success.

[2021-01-15 13:01:23 VRB] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.TokenResult
```

Comment: app_offline.htm is a feature of ASP.NET that prevents AppDomain objects from processing ASP.NET requests. Therefore, I think it will not affect IIS. Will this problem occur in VS?

Comment: You mean having visual studio debug inprocess IIS on the local machine?

Comment: Yes. Will this problem occur if it is not hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that IIS automatically recycles the app if any file changes in the directory. I had some log files and SQLite files in the folder that was being written to during requests.